# How to insert elements in binary tree from array in C?

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, linked-list, binary-tree

I think the index variable, used to traverse the array containing the node values, should be a global one but C doesn't let me. The left node is working fine but the right node also shows the same value as the left one. In the array containing the values, -1 represent a null node and I used pre-order (root->left->right) to build the tree:

[image: tree]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct no{
    int data;
    struct no * left;
    struct no * right;
}node;
node* building_node(int);
node* building_binary_tree(int*,int,node*);
int main()
{
    system("clear||cls");
    int a[]={4,2,9,-1,-1,8,-1,-1,7,-1,-1};
    node*root=NULL;
    root=building_binary_tree(a, -1,root);
    printf("The Binary Tree Has:\n\n");
    printf("root = %d \n",root->data);
    printf("root->left = %d \n",root->left->data);
    printf("root->right = %d \n",root->right->data);
    // printf("%d ",root->left->left->data);
    // printf("%d ",root->left->right->data);
}
 
node * building_node(int data)
{
    //for building an empty node with data
    node* newnode=(node*)calloc(1,sizeof(node));
    newnode->data=data;
    newnode->right=NULL;
    newnode->left=NULL;
    return newnode;
}

node* building_binary_tree(int* a,int index,node* root)
{  
    //for building the tree recursively
    index++;
    if(a[index]==-1) return NULL;
    root=building_node(a[index]);
    root->left=building_binary_tree(a,index,root->left);
    root->right=building_binary_tree(a,index,root->right);
    return root;
}
```

Comment: You don't want to make index a global variable.  You pass the same index to both left and right tree in `building_binary_tree()`.

Comment: ya but it is still not working

Comment: Can you show the right order then for the same tree here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mF6o3Lu7V-9Athb54pK6HDQULeFXP6SJ? and ya that may be the case

Comment: Please insert image here instead of an external link.

Comment: ok the breath first order should be then a={4,2,7,9,8,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}  but it is still showing the same value for left and right

Comment: Use your debugger or just add `printf` to track the value of `index` across the recursive calls. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty normal to have a different signature for the root node `build_tree()` than the remaining nodes `build_subtree()`.  In this case we want to hide the implementation detail on how we advance through the array.

You can use `index` like you did, but you need to caller how far you get.  This means a pointer to your index (`*index`).  I elected to instead pass the address of the pointer to the array itself (`**a`).  Then we just build the current node and recursive build the left and right subtrees.

As a bonus (and to ease debugging) I added a `print_tree()` so we can inspect the whole tree not just the root and it's 2 children.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} node;

node * build_node(int data) {
    node* n = malloc(sizeof *n);
    n->data = data;
    n->right = NULL;
    n->left = NULL;
    return n;
}

node *build_subtree(int **a) {
    if(**a == -1) return NULL;
    node *n = build_node(**a);
    (*a)++;
    n->left = build_subtree(a);
    (*a)++;
    n->right = build_subtree(a);
    return n;
}

node *build_tree(int *a) {
    return build_subtree(&a);
}

void print_subtree(node *n, size_t level) {
    if(!n) return;
    level++;
    print_subtree(n->right, level);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3 * (level - 1); i++)
        printf("%c", ' ');
    printf("%d <\n", n->data);
    print_subtree(n->left, level);
}

void print_tree(node *n) {
    print_subtree(n, 0);
}

int main() {
    node *root = build_tree(
       (int []) {4, 2, 9, -1, -1, 8, -1, -1, 7, -1, -1}
    );
    print_tree(root);
}
```

and the output is (your picture rotated 90 degrees counter clock wise):

```
   7 <
4 <
      8 <
   2 <
      9 <
```

Comment: yup, I did, ty :)